# Yes/No Is $\frac{ \mathbb{Q}[x] }{<x+2>}$ is Field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> ## Is $\frac{ \mathbb{Q}[x] }{<x+2>}$ is  Field ?

My attempt :   I  don't think it is  field because $ x+2$  is reducible in $\mathbb{Q[x]}$ and for field $ x+2$  must be irreducible in $\mathbb{Q[x]}$

Is its true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is $\;x+2\;$ reducible in $\;\Bbb Q[x]\;$ ...or even in $\;\Bbb R[x]\;,\;\;\Bbb C[x]\;$ ? It is a linear polynomial and it is thus irreducible, which makes the ideal $\;\langle x+2\rangle\;$ prime and thus maximal (why?), and thus $\;\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x+2\rangle\;$ is a field.

Be sure you can follow and understand all the above, and try now to answer: to what very well known field is the quotient isomorphic?

Comment: Thanks u sir @DonAntonio. But one more doubt if  I take $ x^2 -1$ then $Q[x]/x^2 -1$ will not field . Is its True ??

Comment: @jasmine That is true, since $\;x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)\;$ is reducible...

Comment: @jasmine You can try to prove it directly. Take the factor class that is represented by $x-1$, i.e. $p(x)=x-1+(x^2-1)q(x)$. All polynomials in the class has zero at $x=1$. Is it the zero class? Is it possible to find $r(x)$ such that $p(x)r(x)=[1]$?

Comment: @A.Γ. i thinks  Not possible

Comment: @jasmine Right, because all polynomials $p(x)r(x)$ are going to have zero at $x=1$ as well.